# How do recursive struct-defined types work in C?

Tags: c, struct, typedef, declaration

I'm trying to define a linked list type from a structure in C. It would be easy for me to do this as a struct, but structs appear not to work with the sizeof() method, which is inconvenient for my purposes; though I could figure out the size of my linked list struct manually, I'd rather avoid a "magic number" situation.

That being said, I'm unaware how to get this to work properly. The code that would ideally work would be:

```
typedef struct { 
   int data;
   linked_list* next;
} linked_list;
```

However, as linked_list is still undeclared by the time the linked_list* variable needs to be declared, this doesn't work.

So, what's the actual way of dealing with this? I'm imagining I have to somehow declare the linked_list type in advance, but Googling "c type declaration" doesn't really get me anywhere. My extremely limited and sketchy experience with C++ hints to me that a header file might be useful in this situation, but I'm not exactly sure how.

Comment: `typedef struct ll ` ... `struct ll *next;`. Classical indeed.

Comment: Your first paragraph makes no sense. structs don't work with sizeof?